# Copy Django App to a New Project but Model Data is Lost

Tags: python, django

I made a development django project on my pc, and I added a bunch of data for one of the apps "things" by logging in the ADMIN panel. When I copy and paste this app folder into a new project on Ubuntu, add this app in setting, then I find all the data in the model is gone. I used "makemigrations, migrate". Still nothing. What should I do to have those data in this new project?

Comment: Your data is stored in your database not in app.

Comment: I guessed so, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Copy your database

Comment: It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments it seems that some kind of a solution has already been found. Here I'd like to give my 2 cents.

Django offers command line tools for exporting and importing data. With

```
python manage.py dumpdata app_label > backup.json
```

you can export all the data for the app `app_label` and save it into a file `backup.json`.

Later you can use this file to load the data:

```
python manage.py loaddata backup.json
```

There are many other options, please check the official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) for further info, like for example using XML instead of JSON and much more.

EDIT:

If you search for **dumpdata** in the questions tagged with **django** here at SO, you'll get many hundreds results.

Comment: This especially useful, when you move from one DBMS to another. E.g. from local sqlite3 to production postgreSQL.